# The science behind Andrew Niccol's film "Anon"

Tags: science-fiction, anon

How does the "ether" work in the film [*Anon* (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5397194/)? The movie differentiates between real memories and recorded "files", but treats both of them as hack-able and manipulable. Unless all the people in this world are "replicants" or exist in "The Matrix" none of the plot-lines make sense. At the very least, this film is hard to take seriously or rate well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic premise of the movie includes that everyone is hooked up to a central system, to which everything that people see is backed up.  This permits authorised users (such as the police) to review the last moments of someone's life, thus allowing them to identify a murderer for example.

This appears to be achieved through some kind of implant.  The hacker community in `Anon` are those who can get into the files of others and manipulate them to remove any evidence of wrongdoing etc.  The Girl (her name is never provided) appears to be able not only to do this but is able to hack the implants in real time, forcing people to see what she wants and leaving them unable to trust their own eyes.